# Результат запроса в массив

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
$autocomplete = "SELECT  productid
                                  FROM vtiger_products";
                $db = PearDatabase::getInstance();

                $result = $db->pquery($autocomplete);
                $count_row = $db->num_rows($result);

                $valueArray = array();

                if ($count_row > 0) {
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $count_row; ++$i)
                        {
                                $valueArray[$i]['productid'] = $db->query_result($result, $i, 'productid');
                        }}
```

Который на выходе дает такой массив [результат](http://joxi.ru/a2XGyvKu88pBmg)

Как можно получить массив в таком виде:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 17
    [5] => 18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто убрать ['productid']

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_row; ++$i)
  {
      $valueArray[$i] = $db->query_result($result, $i, 'productid');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

выкинуть на помойку PearDatabase и юзать ПДО:

```
$sql = "SELECT productid FROM vtiger_products";
$valueArray = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

не понимаю тягу некоторых пользователей похапе разводить турусы на колесах для каждой элементарной операции

Почитал про эту peardatabase. Это просто уму не растяжимо, сколько кода можно написать, чтобы реализовать функциональность, которая *и так есть в ПДО*.

И главное в итоге все равно говнокодить в стиле вайл роу равно мауэскуэль фетч эррэй...